# problema con .gitignore en C#

Tags: git, gitignore

Tengo un problema con git. Al incluir tipo de archivos o carpetas, el .gitignore no me las detecta por alguna razon que desconozco.

Las carpetas que necesito excluir son las "bin" y "obj" o cualquier archivo con extencion ".dll", ".pdb" y ".cache"

Dejo el el codigo fuente del .gitignore y una captura de gitBash para que vean

GitBash

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

.gitignore

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

El `.gitignore` solo funciona si los archivos no han sido agregados al proyecto. A grandes rasgos, si los archivos son parte de la versión anterior, el `.gitignore` no hace diferencia.

En general, hay dos formas de atender la situación.

## La Fácil

Borra los archivos (con `git rm --cached` si los quieres mantener en tu árbol de trabajo y no perderlos) y acomete. De esta forma los archivos van a desaparecer del proyecto *a futuro*. Esto no está libre de problemas. Si otro desarrollador hace un pull/merge de esa rama/revisión, los archivos van a desaparecer de su árbol de trabajo. De la misma forma, si tu haces checkout de una revisión donde los archivos todavía estaban en git, primero git se va a quejar.... si haces el checkout igualmente con `--force`, cuando *regreses* a una revisión más nueva donde los arvchivos ya no están en git, los archivos van a desaparecer. De pronto son productos del build process? En ese caso nada de esto es mayor problema.

## La Difícil (pero correcta)

Hay que reescribir la historia del proyecto para que los archivos no estén nunca en el proyecto. Reescribir la historia tiene sus complicaciones y no me voy a extender a explicarlas. Baste decir que reescribir la historia de un proyecto donde hay varios desarrolladores no debe ser una decisión tomada a la ligera. [1] Para ello, en estos días se recomienda usar `git filter-repo` https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/

[1] Siempre he pensado que si los desarrolladores saben los que están haciendo y saben usar bien `git rebase`, reescribir la historia no debería ser un *ran* problema. Si la historia se reescribe y yo tengo 3 commits en una rama privada, luego de que la historia se reescriba, usando `git rebase` voy a poder montarme sobre la historia nueva en un santiamén, pero aparentemente esto representa una gran dificultad para mucha gente así que siempre se recomienda pensarlo bien antes de hacerlo. De cualquier forma, requiere coordinación por parte del equipo para que todos sepan lo que está pasando. Si un desarrollador por no estar enterado hace un merge usando la historia *vieja*, se pierde el trabajo (siempre se puede eliminar el merge, obvio... pero igual representa *mas* trabajo).

Comment: Perfecto!
Tienes razon, el archivos ya son par de la vida del control de versiones
Lo bueno es que el proyecto tiene un par de commits asi que lo que hare es arrancar de cero de nuevo excluyendo los archivos que no sirven.

muchas gracias!!

Comment: Si el proyecto está recién arrancado, entonces mucho mejor. Es un gran dolor de cabeza si es un proyecto grande, de larga data y con mucha gente.